# RestSharp cancelando a operação

Tags: c#, restsharp

Boa tarde,
Eu tenho uma aplicação que via RestSharp faço uma chamada na Service da Receita para recuperar as informações que eu preciso.

Porém como uso um serviço de terceiros, não sabemos quando este serviço poderá ficar fora do ar. E fazendo minha requisição, não tenho retorno deles e fica travado.
Gostaria de saber se no RestSharp eu tenho algo como um timeout que se eu passar um determinado tempo e nao tiver a resposta ele sai desse serviço e retorna na minha página.

Alguém ja passou por isso? Ou algo similar?

Comment: Clique em [edit] e poste o trecho da requisição, que fica mais fácil de um retorno.

Comment: Já tentou a propriedade `Timeout` da `RestRequest`?

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela resposta. Era isso mesmo Leandro, falou um timeout no RestRequest.